# datetime issue when create a new subscription in Stripe - when subscription buyed from the users timezone

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-cashier

I am trying to create subscription in stripe through php sdk. subscription created successfully but here is the issue,When i create a subscription from UTC timezone my date is 2021-01-08 13:05:25 but in the dashboard subscription created in 2021-01-07 23:35. Also in the stripe response gave me 2021-01-08 13:05:25.my data is generated according to the 2021-01-08. so i am confused, my subscription is deduct on next 7 or 8.

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough or I missed something.

Comment: Please show the code that you're using.

Comment: @anyber I am useing simple create function.
$subscriptions = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
                'customer' => $customer_id,
                'items' => [
                    ['price' => $package->product_strip_id],
                ]
            ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check laravel application timezone in /config/app.php

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Set it as UTC